# Como usar .toggle() para trocar animações

Tags: javascript, jquery, animação

Estou tentando alternar a animação de uma `div` usando `.toggle()`, mas esta `div`, que é a primeira bola cinzenta, simplesmente desaparece após eu clicar no botão (bola laranja), em vez de voltar à sua posição inicial.

```
function main() {
    $('.mainBtn').click(function(){
        console.log("bolaxa");
        $('#btn1').toggle(
            function () {
                $(this).animate({left:'250px'}, 300);
            },
            function () {
                $(this).animate({right:'250px'}, 300);
            }

        );
    });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Aqui está o JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s7q8qt0u/.
Como posso fazer a bola voltar ao seu lugar inicial?

Grato!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso acontece porque estás a adicionar `250px` positivos no segundo `.animate()` que faz a alternação da animação, enquanto deverias fazer a animação voltar novamente para `left:'0'` em vez disso, que é o seu lugar inicial, não para `250px` positivos.

```
$('.mainBtn').click(function(){
    $('#btn1').toggle(function () {
            $(this).animate({left:'250px'}, 300);
        },
        function () {
            $(this).animate({left:'0'}, 300); // Aqui volta para o Zero, lugar inicial
        }
    );
});
```

Aqui tens um exemplo online: https://jsfiddle.net/s9zkhw7p/